# bar button in opaque navigation bar is not appearing ios

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I wanted to put left bar button on opaque navigation bar. I have used following code:

```
var barButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "img_btn_slidemenu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: referenceViewController, action: "btnSideMenuClicked")
navigationController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Still i am not able to view the button what might be mistake? please help me to resolve.Thanks

Comment: Hello Jalak, Are you trying to put bar button on RootViewController of NavigationController?

Comment: @Pradip Vanparia yes putting on navigationItem cant we add?

Comment: Hey Jalak, Can you send me your demo code? so,I can check what actual problem with bar button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```